# why does webpack transfer require.config to undefined?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use *webpack*, version 3.5.5 and *requirejs*, version 2.3.5. But it seems that *webpack* could't resolve *requirejs.config* currently. this is the demo:

**webpack config**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
  entry: './statics/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: './statics/bundle.js',
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: './statics',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery.min',
    person: 'person'
  }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'person'], function($, Person) {
  console.log($().jquery);
  const boy = new Person('bob');
  boy.say();
});
```

***bundle.js***

```
define(function() { return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    undefined;

    requirejs(['jquery', 'person'], function($, Person) {
      console.log($().jquery);
      const boy = new Person('bob');
      boy.say();
    });

/***/ })
/******/ ])});;
```

You can see that webpack complied `requirejs.config` to `undefined`. I need to understand why?

This will lead to browser couldn't load script use a currently path.